# How to handle a map looking and check the value

Tags: scala, dictionary

I need to fix this statement because it isn't using the .get method that uses the Option.

```
if(!map.contains(myKey) ||
    map(myKey) == file.getTimestamp.getTime.toString) {

  ..
}
```

I want to do the lookup the correct way using:

```
map.get(myKey)
```

But I can't get the syntax correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`map`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Option.html#map[B](f:A=>B):Option[B]):

```
map.get(myKey).map(_ == file.getTimestamp.getTime.toString)
```

`map` applies a function to an `Option` and returns another `Option`. In the code above, `map` applies the function `_ == file.getTimestamp.getTime.toString` to the result of `map.get(myKey)`:

- If `map.get(myKey)` is a `Some`, meaning a value for `myKey` exists in the map, then we check whether that value equals `file.getTimestamp.getTime.toString`. If the value does equal that string, we return a `Some(true)`; otherwise we return a `Some(false)`.
- If `map.get(myKey)` is a `None`, meaning a value for `myKey` does not exist in the map, then we return `None`.

The below pattern matching illustrates one way to extract the result of the `map` operation in a manner that is consistent with the `if` statement in your question:

```
map.get(myKey).map(_ == file.getTimestamp.getTime.toString) match {
  case None | Some(true) => ...
  case _ => ...
}
```

@YuvalItzchakov's comment in another answer uses [`getOrElse`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/Map.html#getOrElse(key:K,default:=>V):V) after calling `map`:

```
map.get(myKey).map(_ == file.getTimestamp.getTime.toString).getOrElse(true)
```

This is how `getOrElse` works:

- If the result of the `map` operation is a `Some`, then the value of the `Some` is returned. So either `true` or `false` is returned.
- If the result of the `map` operation is a `None`, then the default value that is passed to `getOrElse`--in this case, `true`--is returned.

If you choose to use `map` to solve your problem, I would go with the `getOrElse` approach that @YuvalItzchakov offered.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional [context](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) regarding _how_ and/or _why_ it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now! Please [edit] your answer to add an explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. It also doesn't hurt to mention why this answer is more appropriate than others.

Answer (score 2):

I think this achieves the logic you're after.

```
if (map.get(myKey).fold(true)(_ == file.getTimestamp.getTime.toString) {
  ...
}
```

Use `fold` to unwrap the `Option` and provide different branches for `Some` and `None`.

Comment: Interesting.  Is it possible using a map?

Comment: @Blankman Modifying @chunjef answer a bit: `map.get(myKey).map(_ == file.getTimestamp.getTime.toString).getOrElse(true)`